# What is the meaning of "got drunk" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "got drunk" in the following sentences,

> “Get” can also mean to fetch something or to cause something to
>   happen.  One can use “get” to command someone to do something. See the
>   examples below.
>
> - James got drunk at the party.  (James was “caused” to become drunk …)
> - Elsie got her hair cut today and she looks lovely.  (Elsie “caused” her hair to be cut…)
> - We get our clothes washed at the laundry.  (We “cause” our clothes …)

( Source : http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-get-and-have/ )

Does "James **got drunk** at the party" mean "James, because of something or something,  was drunk at the party (=> Does it mean that James was drunk by someone or something, not because he wanted to be drunk by himself?)" ?

Does "James was caused to become drunk at the party" mean "James, because of someone or something, was drunk at the party"?

Does "Elsie **got her hair cut** today" mean "Elsie, because of someone or something, cut her hair (=> Elsie went to the beauty salon because not she wanted to cut her hair, because but her father forced her to cut her hair)" ?

Does "We **get our clothes washed** at the laundry" mean "We, because of someone or something, washed our clothes at the laundry (=> We washed our clothes because not we wanted to wash our clothes, because but our mother forced us to wash our clothes)" ?

Does "Elsie have her hair cut" mean "Elsie went to the beauty salon because not her father forced her to cut her hair, because but she wanted to cut her hair"?

Comment: Did you take a look at the different meanings and uses of *get* in a dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get

Answer (score 1):

"Get", besides "acquire", can mean "become".

> James got drunk at the party.

In the above example, James *became* drunk at the party. He probably drank a lot of alcohol. It could have been by himself or someone else made him drink a lot. He just *became* drunk.

---

> Elsie got her hair cut today and she looks lovely.
>   We get our clothes washed at the laundry.

In both those sentence, "get" doesn't mean "to acquire" or "to become". Instead, this is a common *verb phrase*:

> "to get + something + V3 (passive)".

In Elsie's case, the *Subject* (Elsie) did something (went to the salon; let a friend cut it; cut her hair herself; etc) that resulted in her hair "being cut", which is *Passive*.